# Webscraping data from a json source into a csv

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, web-scraping, request

I'am trying to get some information from a website with python, from a webshop.

I tried this one:

```
my_url = requests.get(https://www.telekom.hu/shop/categoryresults/?N=10994&contractType=list_price&instock_products=1&Ns=sku.sortingPrice%7C0%7C%7Cproduct.displayName%7C0&No=0&Nrpp=9&paymentType=FULL)

data = my_url.json()

name = data['MainContent'][0]['contents'][0]['productList']['products'][0]['productModel']["displayName"]
price = data['MainContent'][0]['contents'][0]['productList']['products'][0]['priceInfo']['priceItemSale']["gross"]
url= data['MainContent'][0]['contents'][0]['productList']['products'][0]['productModel']["url"]

for mc in data['MainContent']:
    for co in mc:
        for prod in co['productList']['products']:
            name = prod['productModel']['displayName']
            price = prod['priceItemSale']['gross']
            url = prod['productModel']['url']

filename = "test.csv"
csv_writer = csv.writer(open(filename, 'w'))
headers = "Name, Price, Link\n"
f.write(headers)
f.close()
```

In this webshop there are a lot of product with these attribute "productModel", but how can i get these all and write into a csv? I want web-scraping the name, the price and the url link this page in differents cells but it isn't working.

*
EDIT:

```
def proba():

    my_url = requests.get('https://www.telekom.hu/shop/categoryresults/?N=10994&contractType=list_price&instock_products=1&Ns=sku.sortingPrice%7C0%7C%7Cproduct.displayName%7C0&No=0&Nrpp=9&paymentType=FULL')
    data = my_url.json()
    results = []
    products = data['MainContent'][0]['contents'][0]['productList']['products']
    for product in products:
        name = product['productModel']['displayName']
        try:
            priceGross = product['priceInfo']['priceItemSale']['gross']
        except:
            priceGross = product['priceInfo']['priceItemToBase']['gross']
        url = product['productModel']['url']
        results.append([name, priceGross, url])
    df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Name', 'Price', 'Url'])    
# print(df)  ## print df
    df.to_csv(r'/usr/src/Python-2.7.13/test.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )

while True:
    mytime=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    while mytime < "23:59:59":
    print mytime
    proba()
    mytime=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: are you just need to write name,price,url inside csv file i am right?

Comment: yes, it is my goal, row to row (in every row with 3 cells with these informations)

Comment: but "priceItemSale" key is not available in your everyproduct

Comment: maybe priceItemToBase?

Comment: i have added code in answer box check it once

Comment: Please don't move the goalposts on questions. If you have a new question about how your current question fits into your overall project please ask that as a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all the items have the same number of keys so you cannot access with  `prod['priceItemSale']['gross']` throughout. You need to decide where to get value from when that is not present. Example below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

my_url = requests.get('https://www.telekom.hu/shop/categoryresults/?N=10994&contractType=list_price&instock_products=1&Ns=sku.sortingPrice%7C0%7C%7Cproduct.displayName%7C0&No=0&Nrpp=9&paymentType=FULL')
data = my_url.json()
results = []
products = data['MainContent'][0]['contents'][0]['productList']['products']
for product in products:
    name = product['productModel']['displayName']
    try:
        priceGross = product['priceInfo']['priceItemSale']['gross']
    except:
        priceGross = product['priceInfo']['priceItemToBase']['gross']
    url = product['productModel']['url']
    results.append([name, priceGross, url])
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Name', 'Price', 'Url'])    
# print(df)  ## print df
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

---

Output:

[image]

Comment: It is writing to csv only 1 (only 1 product).

Comment: Not for me it isn't. I get 9.

Comment: I run it with a cycle, maybe it is overwriting and thats why i get 1 row when i stop my "script" and open the csv?

Comment: I don't understand. The above is already looping all products retrieved from the url. If you are looping other urls then you need to amend to merge all dataframes before writing to csv.

Comment: I edited my question with my code with thic "infinity" cicle. If i am using this one, i get only 1 row.

Comment: You should ask that as a new question as I answered your original question. It now looks like you have another question about how you can keep grabbing data in a loop until a specified time - updating or overwriting an existing dataset in Excel.

Comment: This isn't a new question, i get only 1 row with this code in my csv file.

Comment: Run my code as is and you will see all the rows. Your question didn't show a function within a loop. Your edit now shows this. You also have no return statement for your function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864659/webscraping-data-from-a-json-source-why-i-get-only-1-row , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
my_url = requests.get("https://www.telekom.hu/shop/categoryresults/?N=10994&contractType=list_price&instock_products=1&Ns=sku.sortingPrice%7C0%7C%7Cproduct.displayName%7C0&No=0&Nrpp=9&paymentType=FULL")

data = my_url.json()
datas=data["MainContent"][0]["contents"]
finaldata=[]
for mc in datas:
  plist=mc["productList"]["products"]
  for p in plist:
    name =p['productModel']['displayName']
    try:
      price = p['priceInfo']['priceItemToBase']['gross']
    except:
      price=p['priceInfo']['priceItemSale']['gross']
    url = p['productModel']['url']
    finaldata.append([name,price,url])
files=open("data.csv",'w+')
columns = ['Name', 'Price', 'Url']
files.write(",".join(columns))
files.write("\n")
for f in finaldata:
 files.write('{},{},{}\n'.format(f[0],f[1],f[2]))
```

Comment: but there are only 9 element can you give how much element(product ) are there